# UIView.animate called in didMoveToSuperview unexpectedly affects all subviews

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm working on a custom UIView. I got it all working properly, but my design requirements dictate that parts of the view should animate upon load.

My view is set in the following way, and I chose to animate constraints:
[image: UIView layout]

So I called `UIView.animate()` in `didMoveToSuperview()` like such:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    animateArrow()
}

private func animateArrow() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.arrowLeadingConstraint.constant += 15
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm not doing anything else. On its own, the animation only affects the leading constraint of my arrow image view. As expected, and as it should. I can verify this when I start the animation upon user interaction, as pictured below.

[image: Arrow animation on user interaction]

Now, the problem is, when called from within `didMoveToSuperview()`, the animation somehow affects all subviews of my custom UIView...

[image: Animation on didMoveToSuperview]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Impossible to say, since you are animating a constraint, but you haven't posted how your constraints are set up.

Comment: @mag_zbc I've updated the question with the layout of my view

Comment: try this instead: `private func animateArrow() { self.layoutIfNeeded(); self.arrowLeadingConstraint.constant = 31; UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {  }, completion: nil) }`, that is logically a more proper way to do.

Comment: Try calling in `drawRect` method it will be called after things get layout.

Comment: @holex what you suggested doesn't do anything when called from `didMoveToSuperview()`.

Comment: @Skwiggs, that is a good sign of _why_ not calling it from a did-move-super-view is a good idea – call it from the `didMoveToWindow()` method then.

Comment: @holex that doesn't do anything either. I mean in your suggestion the animations block is empty so wouldn't that be the cause ?

Comment: @AmberK your suggestion did it. Works as expected now. If you could write it up as a solution I'll mark it accepted :)

Comment: @Skwiggs, *corrected: `private func animateArrow() { self.layoutIfNeeded(); self.arrowLeadingConstraint.constant = 31; UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil) }`, but you should have spotted on your own as well ;)

Comment: @holex ok now it works. Thanks

Comment: @holex can you write the solution as an answer ? Then I can mark it as selected solution. Also would be good to explain or link to why it's possible to just animate `layoutIfNeeded()`, that proved very unintuitive to me :) (basically explain your comment "that is logically a more proper way to do")

Comment: @Skwiggs, I made the answer, I hope that makes a little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the devil is in your `animateArrow()` method itself, if you amend the method a little bit like e.g. this:

```
private func animateArrow() {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.arrowLeadingConstraint.constant = 31 // = 15 + 16 from your original code

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

*tada*, the animation will work properly as you expected.

---

#### why...?

my explanation may not be academic here but I hope it will make sense to the readers for getting a better understanding.

so, briefly, when you are dealing with constraints you are implicitly dealing with a set of predefined *relationships between the view and its surroundings*. that is why you cannot animate an individual constraint successfully (your original attempt) because only these *relationships* are animatable in this context – not the constraints.

therefore **you will be able to animate the update of all relationships only** *after* you defined the new constraint(s) for your layout – and in principle behind the scenes that could lead to animate every affected view's frame for you in one go.

you can read more about what the constraints are and how the evaluation works with Auto-Layout [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html), if you are interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `didMoveToSuperview` might not be the best idea. Before starting the animation you need to make sure that the layout for all the views on the screen has been done, which might not always be true in `didMoveToSuperview`.

I would move the animation trigger inside `viewDidAppear` in the viewController or in `didLayoutSubviews` which is also in the viewcontroller.

Comment: This is actually a subclass of `UIView`. I'd rather avoid having to trigger the animation from each `UIViewController` that holds it whenever they trigger `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Whoever triggers it needs an overview on the state of the layout. Since the view is not aware of any appearance / disappearance you need to to it in the viewController which has this information. Also, `viewDidLoad` is not the place to start animations, since the layout is not done in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This `UIView` will actually not even be loaded in any `UIViewController` at the moment, it will be programmatically added to some overlay views we have throughout the app

Comment: I see, but those overlays will be presented with an animation I assume? And that animation will have a completion block which can be used to trigger the animation you're showing above. The idea is finding the right hook depending on who is presenting the view.

Comment: Issue seems to be the multiple calls to `didMoveToSuperview` which adds 15 pixels multiple times. Agreed to @marosoaie, animation should be triggered externally Or make sure it's triggered once.

Answer (score 1):

Call the animation code here:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    animateArrow()
}
```

**Or**

as suggested by @**holex** comment: perform a layout pass before:

```
private func animateArrow() { 
   self.layoutIfNeeded(); 
   self.arrowLeadingConstraint.constant = 31; 
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .autoreverse, .repeat]) { 
       self.layoutIfNeeded() 
   } 
}
```

Also add an observer in your `init` if animation stops on pressing home:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredForeground(_:)), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Comment: Somehow, making `animateArrow` use `@objc` and calling it directly with the selector doesn't do anything when coming back to the app. I see `animateArrow()` is being called but it doesn't start animating at that point 